# Is there a way to translate the names of theorems and definitions in other languages, without defining new ones?

Tags: theorems, languages

Is there a way to translate the names of theorems and definitions in other languages, without defining new ones?

For instance, if I use

```
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
```

the word *Proof* is replaced by *Demonstratie*. But I also want to replace all occurences of *Theorem* with *Teorema*.

I know I can use something like

```
\newtheorem{teorema}[theorem]{Teorema}
```

but I don't want to go through the code and replace

```
\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}
```

with

```
\begin{teorema}
...
\end{teorema}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

---

**Update**

I also tried to use

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
```

but I get the error "command \theorem already defined". How can I avoid this?

Comment: Just use `\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}` and keep `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}`; LaTeX doesn't mind what environment name you use.

Comment: @egreg: I tried this too, but I get the error "command \theorem already defined". How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you make a minimal example? You are probably using a class or package that predefines `theorem`.

Comment: @egreg: the project is huge. I use amsthm, but even when I comment it I get the error. I use a template thesis from http://www.latextemplates.com. Can't I just renew or undefine somehow theorem?

Comment: Which one? We can't look at each one of them.

Comment: It is called "thesis". I found a direct link http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/. But maybe I can just renew theorem somehow? Shouldn't be a way to overwrite it no matter what package defined it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to change the names of theorems in the `Thesis.cls` file, you can correct the names in your main TeX file; just add, after you have loaded the other packages (`hyperref` should be last, unless also `cleveref` is used), add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\theorem}{Theorem}{Teorema}{}{}
\patchcmd{\corollary}{Corollary}{???}{}{}
\patchcmd{\lemma}{Lemma}{???}{}{}
\patchcmd{\proposition}{Proposition}{???}{}{}
\patchcmd{\axiom}{Axiom}{???}{}{}
\patchcmd{\example}{Example}{???}{}{}
\patchcmd{\definition}{Definition}{???}{}{}
\patchcmd{\remark}{Remark}{???}{}{}
```

changing each `???` into the proper Romanian word.

Then, using `\begin{theorem}` will print **Teorema** and the same for the other fixed environments. Don't remove the empty groups `{}`: while they seem useless, they are essential for `\patchcmd`.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I did not ask very clearly what I want, but you gave an answer that works perfectly!